# How to select rows in MySQL between initial trimester/year and final trimester/year?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table have this structure:

```
code | item | trimester | year
1       rrr      1         2014
2       fff      3         2014
3       ggg      3         2014
4       hhh      4         2015
5       ttt      2         2016
6       fff      3         2016
```

Now I want to select all items between trimester 3 of 2014 and trimester 1 of 2016, How can you do it?

The result of that query with this example table maybe:

```
2       fff      3         2014
3       ggg      3         2014
4       hhh      4         2015
```

Answer (score 1):

One method:

```
where year * 10 + trimester between 20143 and 20161
```

Alternatively, you could be explicit:

```
where (year > 2014 or (year = 2014 and trimester >= 3)) and
      (year < 2016 or (year = 2016 and trimester = 1))
```